Delayed headline animation until in viewport
I have multiple headlines in a page that I want to animate to be shown word by word.
How can I achieve individual headline animation when they appear in the viewport? Right now all of them are animated on page load.
I have tried to change threshold from 0.1 to 0.8 but no difference.


window.onload = function() {
  const observerOptions = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.1
  }

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.querySelectorAll('span').forEach((span, index) => {
          span.style.setProperty('--word-index', index);
          span.classList.add('reveal');
        });
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      }
    });
  }, observerOptions);

  document.querySelectorAll('.heading-reveal').forEach(target => {
    observer.observe(target);
  });
};
.heading-reveal {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.heading-reveal span {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: revealWord 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--word-index) * 0.25s);
}

@keyframes revealWord {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
<h1 class="heading-reveal">
  <span>Title</span>
  <span>Goes</span>
  <span>Here</span>
</h1>

<h1 class="heading-reveal">
  <span>2nd</span>
  <span>Title</span>
  <span>Here</span>
</h1>

<h1 class="heading-reveal">
  <span>3rd</span>
  <span>Title</span>
  <span>Here</span>
</h1>




I imagine you forgot to add ...  on your h1 tag to reproduce snippet. Your code is functionning and intersectionObserver is working because they are all in the view port add some content and they will animate on entry

I have updated the question with ...
Yes, the code works perfect here but in the page (where the H1 is placed in different sections over the page) all headings are animated in the same time no matter if they are or they are not in the viewport. If I refresh the page on each section containing the H1 it animates but if i enter the page and scroll trough the content when I reach a section with a H1 it is not animated.

You need to create a snippet which actually shows the problem otherwise we can't really help.

Since in your code --word-index is set only after the element is in viewport, all animation-delay is initially 0, and so the animation plays instantly on all elements on page load.
Instead, toggle the animation only when the element is inside the viewport by adding the animation inside the reveal class.
.heading-reveal span.reveal {
  animation: revealWord 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--word-index, 0) * 0.25s);
}



window.onload = function() {
  const observerOptions = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.1
  }

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.querySelectorAll('span').forEach((span, index) => {
          span.style.setProperty('--word-index', index);
          span.classList.add('reveal');
        });
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      }
    });
  }, observerOptions);

  document.querySelectorAll('.heading-reveal').forEach(target => {
    observer.observe(target);
  });
};
.heading-reveal {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.heading-reveal span {
  opacity: 0;
}

.heading-reveal span.reveal {
  animation: revealWord 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--word-index, 0) * 0.25s);
}

.v-100 {
  height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes revealWord {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
<h1 class="heading-reveal">
  <span>Title</span>
  <span>Goes</span>
  <span>Here</span>
</h1>
<div class="v-100"></div>
<h1 class="heading-reveal">
  <span>2nd</span>
  <span>Title</span>
  <span>Here</span>
</h1>
<h1 class="heading-reveal">
  <span>3rd</span>
  <span>Title</span>
  <span>Here</span>
</h1>



